# using of EJB 3 - when is it unnecessary? can it decrease the performance?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

we have an application using EJB3 and enjoy all of it benefits.

anyway, we want to add an external tool to the system which will invoke invoke selected methods from few different EJB's.

despite of need to initazlize a session for using the JPA, won't the few calls for getting EJB for each invocation can even decrease the performance instead of invoking from the implementation class directly?

in this case, what will be the gain of using EJB and not invoking the needed method from the Implementation class directly?

thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question.. can you explain more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an external tool to invoke `EJB`s it's not going to decrease performance.. unless you use `stateful` beans and you have thousands of clients (per hour) - one instance for each client... If you are using `stateless` only one instance for all clients it's going to exist (no decrease here)...

You shouldn't use `JPA` in your external application unless it's a different database... if you have the same database you should access it through `ejb` methtods (another reason why you have them)...

Comment: yes,lets say we have few ejb:
EJB A
EJB B
EJB C

we can write the external tool  which invoke each of the following ejb's methods in order
by using the EJB framework


public class tool
{
EJB 
A a;

EJB 
B b;


EJB 
C c;
public Result runMethods{}
}

or we can implement it by explicitly invoking the methods on the impl classes:



public class tool
{

AImpl a = new..;


BImpl b= new..;



CImpl c= new..;


public Result runMethods{
a.run();
b.run();
...
}
}


won't the injection each time the tool run's will even decrease the performance? what will be the benfits of EJB in that case?

Comment: no.  it will not decrease performance... it's like running in the same jvm...
The benefit of EJB is it's modularity.. for example.. you have an `ejb` on a server and another one on another server.. you can connect to both but you will use different machines..

Comment: i understand, but if all of my runs are local. what would be the benefit? i guess that running the impl directly would be better even if its the same jvm as i don't do anylookup and using instant initalization.

Comment: @Alex `If you are using stateless only one instance for all clients it's going to exist (no decrease here)...` - No, for stateless beans, container maintains pool of bean instances ready to serve requests. Therefore there are multiple instances, it might happen that same instance is picked to serve other request, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: I agree with you Nayan I don't understand where the problem is :d

Comment: @cchaoss because you might want to use other interesting parts of EE :) like AOP (of course you can do it without interceptors as well) but you do everything faster with AOP... and EE is giving you more flexibility.. later you might want to have your app on multiple computers and EE is a great solution... if you have only simple operations maybe you are asking "why do I have to use ejb?".. and the answer is written above :)

Comment: @Alex You mentioned single instance for all clients, which is not true in all case, but for singleton bean.

Comment: if while running this tool there are other users that use the system - all of the stateless EJB's in the pool might be taken and this tool will take place of one users or will not run instantly. if i invoke the iml class directly in a seperate thread without using the container the invocation will be immediately and undependent of other client...therefor i ask if there is any special reason for not doing it. @Alex , isn't AOP avaiable to use within ACC also same as EJB?

Comment: @cchaoss Creating threads isn't recommended, also can invoke implementation class directly but have to manage everything explicitly, container will not be involved.

Comment: yes, thanks. but what will i have to manage if everything will run in a serial way by order? nothing to manage...or am i wrong? can i use the jpa capabaliities using the ACC?

Comment: @cchaoss Transactions, concurrency, consistency etc. which is managed by the container have to be managed explicitly.